# ERROR Found no accessible config files for 'fail2ban' under /etc/fail2ban

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, fail2ban

So my fail2ban wasn't working and in attempts to make it work the config files got messy. Decided to start from scratch.

I ran these as sudo

```
apt-get remove fail2ban

apt-get purge fail2ban

rm -r /etc/fail2ban
```

In hopes I'd completely remove it as the first two commands kept the messy config files.

So now when I apt-get install fail2ban it downloads and installs the package, however has this when I try to run it

```
 * Starting authentication failure monitor fail2ban                                                                                                                                                                            ERROR  Found no accessible config files for 'fail2ban' under /etc/fail2ban
ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
ERROR  Found no accessible config files for 'fail2ban' under /etc/fail2ban
ERROR  Found no accessible config files for 'jail' under /etc/fail2ban
ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
```

These config files are indeed missing. Why aren't they recreated when I reinstalled F2B? How can I start from scratch and reinstall it as default?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Try to `apt-get purge fail2ban` to completely remove the configs and then install again.

Comment: As I wrote in the original post, I've tried that. Thanks though

Comment: But you missed the outputs of all the commands.

Answer (score 6):

I fix the issue with :

```
service fail2ban stop
rm -r /etc/fail2ban/
apt-get purge fail2ban

apt-get install fail2ban
```

Comment: This did it, the trick being to stop fail2ban during the process...

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with some configs and I just solved it. Try to get them from:

```
/usr/share/doc/fail2ban/dist-config
```

You can copy jail.conf and fail2ban.conf to `/etc/fail2ban`

There are other many other sources in folders `action.d/` and `filter.d/` and you can copy then into `/etc/fail2ban/` corresponding folder (as you said).

Answer (score 2):

Download the files you need directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/tree/0.11/config).

```
cd /etc/fail2ban/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/0.11/config/fail2ban.conf
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/0.11/config/jail.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You should list your files in /etc/fail2ban:

```
ls -lh /etc/fail2ban
```

There should be a **jail.conf** and **fail2ban.conf** along with their respective **jail.d** , **fail2ban.d**, **filter.d** and **action.d** directories for the .conf files.

**filter.d** and **action.d** should be populated with several default .conf files for different services.

The error is telling you there are no files.

Also, what do you have in **/var/log/fail2ban.log** ?

Answer (score 0):

*[ssh-ddos]* jail [in fact is served by sshd.conf](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/02525d7b6f96c2841c24c4dbfcfe14e4a3d1ef63).

The solution is to add directive

```
filter = sshd
```

under
*[ssh-ddos]* section

Please note the comment under *[ssh-ddos]* directive that explains the difference:

> This jail corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban. The
> mail-whois action send a notification e-mail with a whois request in
> the body.

This solution worked for me.
Originally found [here](https://itgala.xyz/found-no-accessible-config-files-for-filter-d-sshd-ddos/)